# Square function drawing in r plot

Tags: r

I would like to draw a square function in a r plot like this plot (black line) from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSquareWave.html):

[image]

How can I do this one in R?

Comment: Look into `plot(..., type='s')` or with capital `S`.

Comment: Look into `rect`.  You can make perfect squares.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a definition of the square wave - use the sign function on a periodic function:

```
plot(function(x) sign(sin(x)),-10,10,n=1000)
```

[image: square wave]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lines` to draw any arbitrary pattern by specifying vectors of `x` and `y` coordinates.

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(-2,2))
lines(rep(0:11,each=2),rep(c(-1,1,1,-1),6))
```

That's helpful if you have multiple things you want to plot. But, you can also obtain the same result directly in `plot.default` using the `type='s'` argument:

```
plot(rep(0:11,each=2),rep(c(-1,1,1,-1),6), xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(-2,2), type='s')
```

[image]